# Why does the [language-agnostic] tag exist?

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't any tag that isn't language agnostic be related to a particular language or set of languages? If so, shouldn't it be tagged with those languages? If so, shouldn't all questions not tagged with particular languages or sets of languages be implicitly language agnostic?

If so, why do we have the [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag?

Comment: For questions which are more related to algorithms, but arguably those should be tagged [tag:algorithm] instead.

Comment: I would indeed argue that those should be tagged [algorithm].

Comment: Thanks @Lance, hadn't seen that.

Comment: Also similar: [What does “language agnostic” mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/what-does-language-agnostic-mean)

Comment: @Jason saw that one before posting this (I do *try* to do my research), but I don't consider it to be the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a meta-tag and is therefore deprecated.

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

from [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

To me it's evident enough that "NOT pertaining to a specific language" can't work as the only tag on a question.  Of course, the *problem* with tags with this property is important too:

> These tags are a problem because people don’t realize this and will often use that as the question’s only tag.

I can't verify this happens with `language-agnostic` because any old question was likely aggressively edited to add the real tag.  But I don't see any compelling exceptionalness to this tag.  It's certainly not useful from an SEO standpoint and it's not more interesting of a thing to search for than any other former meta tag is.  Honestly I'm prone to take the uncompromising stance that SO's official policy *is* to not use this if not burninate it and this holds *unless* our entire meta-tag policy is changed, which can include adding exceptions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure we should just burn it outright - this tag is very good for finding questions to answer which are more thought-driven than problem driven. While yes, it is indeed a meta tag, I think this one has *some* merit to stay.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII eek.  Doesn't that kind of open up the "meta-tag" debate again?  I was pretty satisfied with the logic behind that blog post.  e.g. "beginner" is a way to find easy questions I can probably answer but we burninated that anyway.

Comment: Of course it does, but no debate should ever be black and white. Some meta tags are absolutely worthless, but this one may have some purpose to it.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII sure, but I'm basically challenging you to articulate the more general rule that states that this tag is an exception.  I am for burnination; I think this tag happens when people haven't thought about what the question is actually asking.  i.e. it happens when there is a better tag.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII added to my answer to explain why I don't think this is an exception

Answer (score -1):

Implicitly implying tags doesn't work in all cases because questions require at least one tag.

Hence, if a question is language agnostic and other tags don't apply, [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) is the only choice.

Comment: I can't imagine any question that would be welcome on Stack Overflow and not fit any of the tags except "language-agnostic." Can you?