# Meta needs to be agnostic of the [language-agnostic] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

<sup>(Note: this is not a duplicate of [Why does the [language-agnostic] tag exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178847/295232) or [Is [language-agnostic] a meta tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60031/295232;) those pertain to the use of the tag on Stack Overflow)</sup>

The [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag on Meta Stack Exchange has [8 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) and no tag excerpt or wiki. Some of them don't even belong here but are here because they predate Meta Stack Overflow. While it's a common tag on programming-related sites ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)), I can't see a point in discussing language agnosticism on Meta Stack Exchange. Even Meta Stack Overflow doesn't have this tag. Therefore, should we burninate it?

Comment: Attempting to find a valid use of the tag on MSE, which I don't believe has been demonstrated as a necessity by it's prior usage, are questions properly placed on MSE related to multiple site policy regarding both programming and human *language non-specific* topics: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/linguistic-universals/info https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/language-agnostic/info  https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/whats-the-best-way-to-show-a-foreign-language-in-a-manuscript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Maybe the tag would be useful for meta questions about language agnostic main questions relevant for multiple (technical) SE sites. For example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207207/different-questions-for-same-problem-in-different-language-duplicate-or-not
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192705/so-programming-tags-vs-programmers-se-programming-tags
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98353/where-to-ask-more-general-programming-questions
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261772/where-can-i-ask-about-something-i-dont-know-anything-about.

Comment: those are mostly SO related. Amusingly one of the old uses of the tag was a burnination request'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Worse than being a meta-tag it seems actively confusing. It also seems to refer to *human* languages, which is a usage that seems incorrect in context.

I don't think there's going to be much loss in burnination

---

The tag is now burninated:

[image: Trogdor stolen from @Spevacus]

Comment: You forgot Trogdor!